# How to Utilize Alerts from an External Instance for Autoscaling in Google Cloud Managed Instance Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

I have a specific use case where I have an instance running outside of a Managed Instance Group (MIG) in Google Cloud. This instance has custom alert configurations set up to monitor certain metrics or events. Now, I would like to use these alerts as triggers for autoscaling within the Managed Instance Group.

Essentially, the goal is to implement autoscaling based on the alert events generated by the external instance. When an alert is triggered, I want the Managed Instance Group to adjust its size accordingly to handle the increased or decreased workload.

Or

Is it possible to add an instance to a Managed Instance Group while preventing it from being managed by the autoscaler and excluded from scaling actions? (As it possible in aws)

I did looked for pub/sub but didn't feel will be good way.I am new to gcp.